# I'm using filemtime and it keeps returning the following numbers: 1302021664. Why is this?

Tags: php, arrays

When I use the following command:

```
$arrDIR[$filename] = filemtime($filename);
```

It will return "1302021664" for all the `$filename`s in the array `$arrDIR`. Is this suppose to be some kind of date or something?

Comment: Whoever downvoted this question, it's only sensible to explain WHY you did so. It saves others from making the same mistake and receiving the same downvotes; and it saves time. Are we here to throw stones only? Or to use them? Yes, to use stones to build and strengthen this shining edifice :-) Thrown stones make for muddy water, anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is unix time stamp you have to convert it into date

```
$time= filemtime($filename);

echo date('Y-m-d',$time);
```

Answer (score 2):

It's the Unix Timestamp (i.e. the number of seconds since the Epoch, 1/1/1970). You can convert it to human-readable time using the `date( )` function (see http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

So if you wanted it in a UK date-format, you would do:

```
$arrDIR[$filename] = date( 'H:i:s d/m/Y', filemtime($filename) );
```

which would set `$arrDIR[$filename] = "16:41:04 05/04/2011"`

Answer (score 2):

Yes. That's the [UNIX timestamp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) for Tue Apr 05 17:41:04 2011. [`filemtime` gives you a UNIX timestamp.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php)

Answer (score 1):

see http://docs.php.net/filemtime:

> Returns the time the file was last modified, or FALSE on failure. The time is returned as a Unix timestamp, which is suitable for the [date()](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function.

Answer (score 0):

It's a unix timestamp. It shows the seconds from the Unix epoch. See here for more data : http://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php

You can use php's `date()` method to format it : http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 0):

> This function returns the time when the data blocks of a file were being written to, that is, the time when the content of the file was changed.
>   Returns the time the file was last modified, or FALSE on failure. The time is returned as a Unix timestamp, which is suitable for the date() function.

So, it returns the time as a Unix timestamp of when it was last modified.

[Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php)

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is. Its a unix timestamp. See [filemtime()](http://php.net/filemtime) for further information and also [date()](http://php.net/date) on how you can format it.